# Requesting Camera Permission in Flutter Web for Another Web View

Tags: flutter, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

I am working on a Flutter web application where I need to request camera permissions and access the camera stream for another web view. I am using the dart:html library to request camera access with getUserMedia. However, I'm facing issues, and I could use some guidance.

Code to allow the camera for webview but not working

```
onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
          // webViewController = controller;
          controller.evaluateJavascript(source: '''
          navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
            .then(function (stream) {
              // Handle the camera stream for website B
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.error('Error accessing camera in website B:', error);
            });
        ''');
        },
```

Comment: What are the issues you are facing? What does your code look like?

Comment: I am facing an issue in providing the camera access to the web view it is only allowing the camera access to Flutter Web, not the web view I have opened and i updated the code